# How to parse hex values into a uint?

Tags: c#

```
uint color; 
bool parsedhex = uint.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out color); 
//where Text is of the form 0xFF0000
if(parsedhex)
   //...
```

doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try

```
Convert.ToUInt32(hex, 16)  //Using ToUInt32 not ToUInt64, as per OP comment
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind (although it may not apply to this particular integer conversion)... if the input is bad, Convert.ToUInt32 could be orders of magnitude slower than UInt32.TryParse, like Convert.ToDouble vs Double.TryParse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586436/double-tryparse-or-double-convert-what-is-faster-and-more-safe/586539#586539  Also, it's not always clear what it's converting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586436/double-tryparse-or-double-convert-what-is-faster-and-more-safe/586460#586460

Comment: As @Triynko said, this is a faulty process, as it is liable to throw exceptions.  uint.TryParse would be preferable, since it returns a Boolean value indicating success or failure, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: This approach with `Convert.ToUInt32` will handle the '0x' prefix as part of the input.

Answer (score 56):

You can use an overloaded `TryParse()` which adds a NumberStyle parameter to the `TryParse` call which provides parsing of Hexadecimal values.  Use `NumberStyles.HexNumber` which allows you to pass the string as a hex number.

**Note**: The problem with `NumberStyles.HexNumber` is that it *doesn't* support parsing values with a prefix (ie. `0x`, `&H`, or `#`), so you have to strip it off before trying to parse the value.

Basically you'd do this:

```
uint color;
var hex = TextBox1.Text;

if (hex.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
    hex.StartsWith("&H", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) 
{
    hex = hex.Substring(2);
}

bool parsedSuccessfully = uint.TryParse(hex, 
        NumberStyles.HexNumber, 
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
        out color);
```

See the documentation for [TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Int32__) for an example of how to use the NumberStyles enumeration.

Comment: Personally, I'd call this behavior a bug. Why on earth would they call the flag **Allow**HexSpecifier if it doesn't actually allow any hex specifier?

Comment: Keep in mind that there are at least two common hex specifiers out there: 0x and &H

Comment: just found another potential representation: '#0000103A3C..'

Answer (score 16):

Or like

```
string hexNum = "0xFFFF";
string hexNumWithoutPrefix = hexNum.Substring(2);

uint i;
bool success = uint.TryParse(hexNumWithoutPrefix, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out i);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a try-parse style function:

```
    private static bool TryParseHex(string hex, out UInt32 result)
    {
        result = 0;

        if (hex == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            result = Convert.ToUInt32(hex, 16);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```