# C# string to float?

Tags: c#

I have this bit of code here:

```
int i = 0;

        StreamReader re = File.OpenText("TextFile1.txt");
        string input = null;

        while ((input = re.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] sites = input.Split(' ');
            for (int j = 0; j < sites.Length; j++)
            {
                MyArray[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(sites[j]);
            }
            i++;
        }


     for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
     {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(MyArray[a, j] + " ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
     }
```

My problem is this line of code

```
MyArray[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(sites[j]);
```

Its getting converted to an int, how do I convert it to a float?

Comment: float[,] MyArray = new float[5, 5];
MyArray[i, j] = Convert.ToSingle(sites[j]);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MyArray[i, j] = Convert.ToSingle(sites[j]);
```

Answer (score 33):

Try float.Parse(string) or Double.Parse(string)

Answer (score 5):

[Convert.ToSingle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tosingle.aspx) method or [whole bunch of others](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert_members.aspx).

EDIT:
Here's an [related article: Double.TryParse or Double.Convert - what is faster and more safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586436/double-tryparse-or-double-convert-what-is-faster-and-more-safe)  of interest in SO.

Comment: With Convert.ToDouble, I was expecting there to be a Convert.ToFloat. This makes sense though.