# Faster alternative to Convert.ToDouble(string)

Tags: c#, performance

Is there a **faster** way to convert a `string` to `double` than `Convert.ToDouble`?

I have monitored `System.Convert.ToDouble(string)` calls and its degrading my app performance.

```
Convert.ToDouble("1.34515");
```

[image: Perfomance screenshot]

**WORKING ANSWER FROM Jeffrey Sax :**

```
static decimal[] decimalPowersOf10 = { 1m, 10m, 100m, 1000m, 10000m, 100000m, 1000000m }; 
static decimal CustomParseDecimal(string input) { 
    long n = 0; 
    int decimalPosition = input.Length; 
    for (int k = 0; k < input.Length; k++) { 
        char c = input[k]; 
        if (c == '.') 
            decimalPosition = k + 1; 
        else 
            n = (n * 10) + (int)(c - '0'); 
    } 
    return n / decimalPowersOf10[input.Length - decimalPosition];
```

}

[image: After Jeffrey Sax CustomParser]

Comment: well, the obvious thing to do would be to *avoid* the conversion being required in the first place (e.g. keep the data as a double in the first place). That being said, I'm also concerned that something is dealing with "Price", but using doubles (i.e. Decimal should be preferred for such numbers)

Comment: Does the conversion sometimes fail and throw an exception? Exceptions are expensive(But you still can throw a few thousand of them per second). And how often are you calling `ToDouble`? There is no way that 2 calls to `ToDouble` take 5ms. Can you give us the code? And to measure performance execute it *often* and calculate the average.

Comment: I agree with @Damien , that monetary values should be stored in `decimal`, not double, but that doesn't increase performance.

Comment: A quick test showed that my comp can do about 5 million parsings of double per second on a single core. So how much data do you parse for that to be a problem?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: No exception is throw. Debug->Exceptions:All checked.I am simply converting a String to Double and it cost me 50% of my Method execution time in which I am parsing a string of 1200 characters

Comment: Please post a relevant subset of the code. Also 50% of how much total time is relevant too. If your code doesn't do anything expensive, 50% isn't much.

Comment: That's true ;) The only point I could optimise was the Convert.ToDouble. So if there is no alternative, I stay with Double.Parse which seems to be a little bit faster. Thx

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why `Convert.ToDouble` is taking 5 ms on your system, when on mine it takes 0.0003 ms. I'm fairly certain that my 2.0 GHz machine isn't 10,000 times faster than yours.

Comment: @JimMischel: This delay should come from the profiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save about 10% by calling `Double.TryParse` with specific cached instances of `NumberStyles` and `IFormatProvider` (i.e. `CultureInfo`):

```
var style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
double.TryParse("1.34515", style, culture, out x);
```

Both `Convert.ToDouble` and `Double.Parse` or `Double.TryParse` have to assume the input can be in any format. If you know for certain that your input has a specific format, you can write a custom parser that performs much better.

Here's one that converts to `decimal`. Conversion to `double` is similar.

```
static decimal CustomParseDecimal(string input) {
    long n = 0;
    int decimalPosition = input.Length;
    for (int k = 0; k < input.Length; k++) {
        char c = input[k];
        if (c == '.')
            decimalPosition = k + 1;
        else
            n = (n * 10) + (int)(c - '0');
    }
    return new decimal((int)n, (int)(n >> 32), 0, false, (byte)(input.Length - decimalPosition));
}
```

My benchmarks show this to be about 5 times faster than the original for `decimal`, and up to 12 times if you use ints.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks, it really improve the parsing performance !

Comment: @StevenMuhr: Just curious, what improved parsing performance? Saving the culture and style? Or writing your own custom parser?

Comment: @JimMischel: I am using the CustomParseDecimal. It really improve my perf!

Comment: Note that this custom parser has a few limitations: 1) It allows fewer significant digits, but 64 bit should still be enough for most cases 2) It doesn't support a sign 3)  It has no error handling whatsoever.

Comment: Your function is perfect but if you cache input.Length into a variable and use it instead then it significantly sppeds up.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to reproduce this. This code tests the speed of `Convert.ToDouble`.

```
        int numTests = 10000;
        double sum = 0;
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < numTests; ++i)
        {
            var d = Convert.ToDouble("1.23456");
            sum += d;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} tests @ {1} ms. Avg of {2:N4} ms each", numTests,
           sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, (double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/numTests);
        Console.WriteLine("sum = {0}", sum);
```

With 10,000 calls, I get

```
10000 tests @ 3 ms. Avg of 0.0003 ms each
sum = 12345.6000000021
```

That's in release mode, running without the debugger attached.

It's highly unlikely that the problem is with `Convert.ToDouble`.

Comment: I've also checked that the call is not optimized away by the JITter. I've created an array of random numeric strings and used them as arguments. I've achieved a similar time.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `double.Parse("1.34515");` which is what `Convert.ToDouble` wraps.

It may be quicker to call `double.TryParse` which will avoid the exception overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try decreasing the number of calls to `Thread.CurrentCulture` by using the `Double.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0kb11ck8.aspx). Although I doubt it would make a significant difference.

It may occur that parsing to another type: `float` or `decimal` may win a couple percent.

Kind of a mad idea, but... You could cache the `NumberFormatInfo` instance and use reflection to call the internal `System.Number.ParseDouble` directly. This would decrease the number of calls to `NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance()`, but to be honest, I'd expect reflection to be much slower.

The only option left (except for avoiding parsing) is using some custom parsing method. For example, if you define a strict format for the numbers (e.g. `#.####`), you could probably end up with a faster, yet less flexible and/or safe implementation. But taking into account that built-in parsing is half-native, I doubt you'll win.

**UPDATE**

I've analyzed the .NET code a bit more and found out that `NumberFormatInfo` is a `IFormatProvider`. So it seems like the fastest code should be:

```
IFormatProvider _CachedProvider = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
var value1 = double.Parse(str1, NumberStyles.Number, _CachedProvider);
var value2 = double.Parse(str2, NumberStyles.Number, _CachedProvider);
```

This code should decrease the time spent for parsing preparation as much as it's possible. If you parse a lot of string pairse, you could also extract the `IFormatProvider` caching to an external code that (possibly) runs a loop and win another couple of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Function in this post [Faster alternative to decimal.Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645870/faster-alternative-to-decimal-parse/37754822#37754822) is based on Jeffrey Sax's code. It adds support for negative numbers, optimizes performance by caching input.Length into a variable and works also for larger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[`double.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx) should be a little bit faster.

Comment: @StevenMuhr, I find that really strange, since Convert.ToDouble uses double.Parse internally.

Comment: I have rerunned some tests with Parse, I have 5ms. The difference between Convert.ToDouble & Double.Parse is really small unfortunately

Comment: double.Parse() is faster. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586436/double-tryparse-or-convert-todouble-which-is-faster-and-safer?lq=1 .

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure about your source data format **and** range, you can use:

```
string num = "1.34515";
int len = num.Length - num.IndexOf('.') - 1;
int intval = Int32.Parse(num.Replace(".", ""));
double d = (double)intval / PowersOf10[len]; // PowersOf10 is pre-computed or inlined
```

It worked ~50% faster than `Double.Parse` for me, but I wouldn't use it in any serious applications - it's extremely limited compared to proper parsing and I can't think of process where you need to parse millions of doubles and a few milliseconds would make the difference.