# how to convert empty string to double

Tags: asp.net

```
double mrp = Convert.ToDouble(gvRow.Cells[9].Text.ToString());
```

In the above code when `mrp = "6458.0"` it works fine but somtimes when mrp is empty now it throws an exception.kindly help me to solve this issue....

Comment: What should an empty string be converted to? Where is the common sense in the approach to this question? Did you try putting an `if` there to check if it is an empty string? _And why not?_

Answer (score 1):

Use `Double.TryParse`, this will not throw an exception and if the parsing fails then you will get `0` as the parsed value.

```
double number;
if (double.TryParse(gvRow.Cells[9].Text, out number))
{
    //valid
}
{
    //invalid
}

//if invalid then number will hold `0`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx)** to check if the conversion succeeds or not.

```
double mrp;
if (Double.TryParse(gvRow.Cells[9].Text.ToString(), out mrp))
{
   // Success
}
else
{
  // Cannot convert to double
}
```

Also, You might want to use [Double.IsNan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan.aspx)

Comment: I'd put "Joy", "Happiness", and "Wealth" there too :)

Answer (score 1):

you should try this: `double mrp = gvRow.Cells[9].Text.ToString() != "" ? Convert.ToDouble(gvRow.Cells[9].Text.ToString()): 0.0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Double.TryParse(gvRow.Cells[9].Text.ToString(), out mrp))
   Console.WriteLine("Ok");
else
   Console.WriteLine("not a number");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double.Tryparse..

```
 double num; 

if(Double.Tryparse(gvRow.Cells[9].Text.ToString(),num) 
{
  // get the converted value
}
else
{
  //invalid
}
```

Comment: It's not a good answer. It doesn't change anything. How can it convert something like "HEY" to double? It'll throw an exception again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Double.TryParse as others talked about.

But as an alternative way, you can validate your cells by data type checking, or it shouldn't be null etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try   double.tryParse

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586436/double-tryparse-or-double-convert-what-is-faster-and-more-safe)

```
Convert.ToDouble will throw an exception on non-numbers
Double.Parse will throw an exception on non-numbers or null
Double.TryParse will return false or 0 on any of the above without generating an exception.
```