# Parallel.for causes different results

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, locale, cultureinfo

I am currently trying to improve a C# project I am working on. Specifically, my goal is to parallelize some operations to reduce processing time.
I am starting with small snippets just to get the hang of it.
The following code (not parallel) works correctly (as expected)

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
     double d;
     try
     {
          d = Double.Parse(lData[i]);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         throw new Exception("Wrong formatting on data number " + (i + 1) + " on line " + (lCount + 1));
     }
     sg[lCount % N][i] = d;
}
```

By using the following (parallel) code I would expect to obtain the exact same results, but that is not the case.

```
Parallel.For(0, M, i =>
{
    double d;
    try
    {
        d = Double.Parse(lData[i]);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Wrong formatting on data number " + (i + 1) + " on line " + (lCount + 1));
    }
    sg[lCount % N][i] = d;
});
```

The part of the program these snippets are from reads data from a file, one line at a time. Each line is a sequence of comma-separated double precision numbers, that I put in the vector lData[] using String.Split(). Every M lines, the data sequence starts over with a new data frame (hence the `% M` in the element index when i assign the values).

It is my understanding (clearly wrong) that by putting the code from the (serial) for-loop in the third parameter of `Parallel.For` I parallelize its execution. This shouldn't change the results. Is the problem in the fact that the threads are all accessing to lCount and M? Should I make thread-local copies?

Thanks.

(since I'm new I am not allowed to create the `Parallel.For` tag)

EDIT:
I ran some more tests. Basically I looked at an output earlier in the code than what I did before. It would appear that the parallel version of my code does not fill the `sg[][]` array entirely. Rather, some values are left to their defaults (0, in my case).

EDIT 2 (to answer some of the comments):
`lData[]` is a `string[]` obtained by using `string.Split()`. The original string I am splitting is read from my data files. I wrote the code that generates them, so they are generally well-formatted (I still used the `try-catch` construct out of habit). Just before the for-loop (wither parallel or serial) I check to verify that `lData[]` has the correct number of values (M). If it doesn't, I throw an exception that prevents the program from reaching the for-loop in question.
`sg[][]` is a N by M array of type `double` (there was a typo in the snippets, now corrected; In my original code this error was not present). After I read N lines from the file the array `sg[][]` contains a whole data set. After the for-loop (either parallel or serial) there is a portion of come that looks like this:
    lCount++; //counting the lines I have already read
    if((lCount % N) == 0)
    {
        //do things with sg[][]
        //reset sg[][]
    }
So, I am on purpose overwriting all lines of `sg[][]`. The for-loop's whole purpose is to update the values in `sg[][]`.

Comment: Aside: you can increase performance by using `Double.TryParse` instead of exception handling.

Comment: For the missing values, did you receive the exception? Also if your processing depends on order, Parallel.For does not execute in specific order.

Comment: @James: That's not true. Try/catch and Double.TryParse should run at equal speeds, assuming that valid input is supplied. 

try/catch has no performance impact, when no exception is thrown. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973839.aspx#dotnetperftips_topic2

Judging from his example, it is to be assume that the values valid and exceptions are rare. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/586539/455493

But other than that, I agree with it. `Double.TryParse` is a cleaner way to do it. Not necessarily faster.

Comment: You're right. It depends how exceptional invalid data is.

Comment: It't not clear to me what this code should do. Maybe you can be more precise. What is the array sg[] supposed to contain? every time lCount exceeds M, you'll keep overwriting its values. Maybe you meant 'integer division with no remainder' instead of modulo. Also it's not clear why the array ldata must also have M elements. You might have stripped out too much information from the code snippet. I assume your real code might look a bit different and that might explain the problem.

Comment: Could you post a short, but complete sample code that demonstrates this issue, along with the output you're getting from both versions? My guess is that there is something else going on, but it's hard to say without actually seeing the code.

Comment: I edited the OP to answer to these comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some line-by-line debugging over the weekend, I managed to find where the problem was.

Basically, unbeknownst to me, the threads created by the `parallel.for` did not inherit the CultureInfo (this is the normal behaviour of threads, and I didn't know that). What was happening then was that strings like `3.256` were being parsed to `3256.0`. This caused the issues I found with the output.
(Note: the default locale on my computer is set to use a comma as decimal separator, but I had set to the full stop in program.cs for all my code. I had incorrectly assumed this would be inherited by new threads)

The correct parallel snippet looks like this:

```
CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
newCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Parallel.For(0, M, i =>
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    double d;
    try
    {
        d = Double.Parse(lData[i]);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Wrong formatting on data number " + (i + 1) + " on line " + (lCount + 1));
    }
    GlobalVar.sgData[lCount % N][i] = d;
});
```

Thanks to all who pitched in with comments and opinions. Good information to improve my programming.

I updated the question tags to reflect where the issue really was.

Comment: You can take advantage of the  [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx) property instead of setting it explicitly so that it will get inherited by new threads.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the code is *inherently* wrong, as far as I can see.  My guess would be that you have a race condition or closure issue in the function containing the snippets, probably on the variable `N`.

If you have nested this snippet inside of another Parallel.For() call, you may be missing the fact that `N` is closed over in the lambda expression, and may be getting updated.  Therefore while you are off updating 'N', you expect it to stay constant inside of the lambda.  To resolve that, try this:

```
// Create a local copy of N and M, so that if we update 
// it elsewhere it doesn't affect the closure
var n = N;
var m = M;
Parallel.For(0, m, i =>
{
    double d;
    try
    {
        d = Double.Parse(lData[i]);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Wrong formatting on data number " + (i + 1) + " on line " + (lCount + 1));
    }
    sg[lCount % n][i] = d;
});
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this solution. It didn't change the result of the parallel for-loop.