# input is in incorrect format

Tags: c#, .net

```
 protected void BtnCal_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {    double result = 0;
                double width;
                double length;
                double radius;
                double breath;

            radius = (Convert.ToDouble(TextRadius.Text));
            length = (double.Parse(TextLength.Text));
            breath = (double.Parse(TextBreath.Text));
            width = (Convert.ToDouble(TextWidth.Text));

            if (DropDownShapes.SelectedValue == "cir")
            {                        double pi = 3.142;
                result = radius * radius * pi;
                TextWidth.Text = "0";
                TextLength.Text = "0";
                TextBreath.Text = "0";
            }

            else if (DropDownShapes.SelectedValue == "tri")   
          {    result = length * breath * 0.5;
                TextWidth.Text = "0";
                TextRadius.Text = "0";
            }

            else if (DropDownShapes.SelectedValue == "rec")
            {  result = length * width;
                TextRadius.Text = "0";
                TextLength.Text = "0";
                TextBreath.Text = "0"
            }
            else
            {
                TextArea.Text = result.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: With the question being?

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what exactly is the question but maybe you have the problem that there is no double value in one of your TextBox. To solve this you can use double.tryparse instead of Convert.ToDouble or double.parse

```
double.TryParse(TextRadius.Text, out radius);
double.TryParse(TextLength.Text, out length);
double.TryParse(TextBreath.Text, out breath);
double.TryParse(TextWidth.Text, out width);
```

Convert.ToDouble and double.Parse will throw an exeption while double.TryParse will return false if not able to parse.

Also answerd here:
[c# Double.TryParse or Convert.ToDouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586436/double-tryparse-or-convert-todouble-which-is-faster-and-safer)

Comment: Last I checked, `TryParse` takes multiple parameters, and it returns `bool`s to indicate success.

Comment: These lines of code will not compile.  `double.TryParse` takes more than just a single parameter.

Comment: You are both right, thanks for note... I adopted the answer. Not sure if it helps anyway. There are a few more questions about the code from ibtihaj khan... e.g. why is result only shown in else and so on...