# How to load data into program as double? (not string) in c# (window form application - visual studio)

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, double, loaddata

I dont know how to ask, but i want to load data in double not in string as you can see in the code. Can i change them in double? i want to store them in array because i want to find maximum value from the data. cannot find them in string.

```
private void button1_openfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //load data from text file
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Siti Nurhazwani\Desktop\table.txt");
        string[] values;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            values = lines[i].ToString().Split('/');
            string[] row = new string[values.Length];

            for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
            {
                row[j] = values[j];
            }

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        

    }
```

can someone share code to me how to change the string to double? please use simple terms i am a beginner in c#.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number

Comment: You can use either [`double.TryParse()` or `Convert.ToDouble()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586436/double-tryparse-or-convert-todouble-which-is-faster-and-safer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines in your code to double.

```
string[] row = new string[values.Length];

for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
{
    row[j] = values[j];
}
```

Instead

```
double[] row = new double[values.Length];

for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
{
   row[j] = Convert.ToDouble(values[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. Can you do the change from string to double inside the loop? If so, this should be quite easy to solve, try this for example:

`var result = Convert.ToDouble(originalValue)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?view=net-5.0

Comment: i try but error, its say " System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type System.String[] to type System.IConvertible '.' .. What should i do?

Comment: You cannot directly convert string[] to double. But to convert each element of the array.
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var value= Convert.ToDouble(lines[i]);
}
And Siva Makani has provided more detailed code.