# Add hexadecimal from file to List<byte>

Tags: c#, arrays, hex, byte

I'm trying to make a `List<byte>` from a file that contains string (Hexadecimal) .
the definition is :

```
List<byte> myArray = new List<byte>();
```

if I want to add my information directly I use something like this :

```
  myArray.Add(0xb8);
```

Note : Without any quotation or double-quotation .

The problem is when I want to do the same thing from file!
Now I want to know what `0xb8`'s type is so I use the following code :

```
0xc3.GetType().ToString()
```

the result is :       System.Int32  !!!!

but when I read strings from a file and use code like this , it give me the following error .

code :

```
 Line = "0xb8";
myArray.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Line));
```

Error :

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'byte'
```

and it's clear . because the only overload of `myArray` gets only a `byte`as argumant.
What makes thing so complicated for me is why it doesn't give me any error when I add a `Int32` to `myArray` in `myArray.Add(0xb8);` .

I think it should be a form of byte ! maybe !

Why doesn't it give any errors and how can accomplish this scenario (I mean add byte from string to myArray ) ?

Comment: `the result is : System.Int32 !!!! ` of course ... a number. What else could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of that compiler error by just casting the value to `byte`:

```
myArray.Add((byte)Convert.ToInt32(Line));
```

However, when you run that code you will get a different error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.

That's because the `Convert.ToInt32` method doesn't parse hexadecimal numbers out of the box.

You can specify the base when you convert the string to a number:

```
myArray.Add((byte)Convert.ToInt32(Line, 16));
```

Comment: Or you can save yourself the cast and use `Convert.ToByte(Line, 16)` instead...then if you happen to provide a `Line` of "0xF8C4" you can catch an `OverflowException` instead of just quietly truncating to 0xC4

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
var list = new List<byte>();

byte byteValue = 0xb8;
list.Add(byteValue);
```

This doesn't (*"cannot convert from 'int' to 'byte'"*):

```
var list = new List<byte>();

int byteValue = 0xb8;
list.Add(byteValue);
```

Yet in both cases `0xb8` is recognized as `System.Int32`. So why does the compiler allow implicit conversion of an `int` to `byte` in the first example?

See C# spec 6.1.9 Implicit constant expression conversions:

> A constant-expression (§7.19 [including literals]) of type int can be converted to type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the constant-expression is within the range of the destination type.

This exists because all integer literals are either `(u)int` or `(u)long`, as specified in 2.4.4.2 Integer literals.

Given `0 <= 0xb8 <= 255`, the compiler allows the implicit conversion.

In your case, because of reasons [explained by @usr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30865386/266143), you'll need to do an explicit conversion:

```
myArray.Add((byte)Convert.ToInt32(Line, 16));
```

Answer (score 4):

`0xb8` is an integer literal (like `1234`). `"0xb8"` is a string literal (like `"x"`). There is no such thing as a hex literal in C#. It's an int literal in hex format. So that explains the trouble you had with the literals.

Not all of the string parsing functions support hex input. See [this for how to parse a hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98559/how-to-parse-hex-values-into-a-uint).

When a parsing function gives you an `int` and you need to treat it as a `byte`, you can cast: `(byte)myInt`. This is safe because the parsed value is guaranteed to fit into a byte.

In some places the compiler is able to convert automatically for you if you have been using a constant such as `0xb8`. Since you will not have that in practice (you are parsing a file) that case is not relevant for the final code. But this explains why that works.

Comment: his problem is that there is some intelligence in the compiler so that integral literals are converted to the right type by the compiler...

Comment: @xanatos right. *Many* things to explain here! What a surprisingly confusing problem for a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

> How can accomplish this scenario (I mean add byte from string to myArray ) ?

```
List<byte> myArray = new List<byte>();
string Line = "0xb8";
myArray.Add(Convert.ToByte(Line, 16));
```

> why it doesn't give me any error when I add a Int32 to myArray in myArray.Add(0xb8);

compiler can see that `0xb8` is in `Byte` values range

```
myArray.Add(0xb8);  // ok
myArray.Add(0xff);  // ok
myArray.Add(0x100); // cannot convert from int to byte
```