# C# Alphanumeric string to long conversion

Tags: c#

My string is in "abcd123ef" format. I want it to convert in long format like in variable b.
I tried many ways but got exception as  'input string is not in correct format'

Ways I tried are shown below:

1)

```
var a = "ABCD123Ef";
long b = convert.int64(a);
```

2)

```
var a = 'ABCD123Ef';
long b = parse.int64(a);
```

3)

```
long b = convert.int64("ABCD123Ef");
```

Comment: you mean input is hexadecimal? if so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98559/how-to-parse-hex-values-into-a-uint

Comment: Are you trying to convert hex values?

Comment: What do you mean by _long format_ exactly? Can you please be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Its not hexaecimal string...

Comment: then how do you wish to convert it into long? by skipping all non-digit characters? or skipping until you find a first digit? you need to be more specific

Comment: I saw letter 'f' in lowercase but other letters are in uppercase. Look like it is in base64 format?

Comment: @AkkiBhogte - "Its not hexaecimal string..." - well, then what is it? You need to give us more information. Do you know, what the expected `long` value should be? - Please note that `"ABCD123Ef"` (or `"abcd123ef"`) is a `string`, **not** a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

If that is a hex value you can convert like this

```
var b = Convert.ToInt64 (a, 16);
```

Comment: Please advice for example if my string is "abcd123ef" and want to catch it in long b varible then what should be conversion code.?

Comment: that is a `long` you can say `long b =  Convert.ToInt64 ("abcd123ef", 16);`

Comment: Thanks David for instant reply. i will let you know result shortly..!

Comment: David, in variable long b we want "abcd123ef", after using your way we got some number like 12345656 in variable b.

Comment: @AkkiBhogte You want to convert it to a Long. That has to be a number, there can be no aplha characters in a long

Comment: David, Thanks a lot for clarification..!.